# python - collect attribute from a list of objects where attribute exists

Tags: python

What I have below will go through a list of objects and collect and attribute called 'age'.

```
values = [ getattr(x.data, "age", "") for x in nodes ]
>> ['5', '7', '12']
```

However if the attribute 'age' is not there it returns this

```
>> ['5', '', '7', '', '12']
```

How can i modify the line of code so the list generated wont contain empty values.

Comment: `for x in nodes if hasattr(x.data, "age")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter the list after generating it:

```
values = [ getattr(x.data, 'age', '') for x in nodes ]
values = list(filter(bool, values)) # just filter(bool, values) in Python 2
```

Or filter the list while generating it:

```
values = [ getattr(x.data, 'age') for x in nodes if hasattr(x.data, 'age')]
```

Or indeed (comment from Hai Vu), if `'age'` isn't standing in for a string variable, access the field directly without using `getattr`.

```
values = [ x.data.age for x in nodes if hasattr(x.data, 'age')]
```

**Update:**

Following your further question, in `x.data.age`, `data.age` is *not* an attribute of `x`.
`data` is an attribute of `x`, and `age` is an attribute of the value held by `x.data`. You can check both stages of the attribution if necessary:

```
values = [x.data.age for x in nodes if hasattr(x, 'data') and hasattr(x.data, 'age')]
```

Comment: +1. If you use `hasattr`, might as well access age directly: `[x.data.age for x in nodes if hasattr(x.data, 'age')]`

Comment: is it possible to write it in a way which it checks for the full property path? like this = `values = [ getattr(x, 'data.age') for x in nodes if hasattr(x, 'data.age')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use values.remove('') which will remove only first empty value.
To remove all empty values:

```
values = [ getattr(x.data, "age", "") for x in nodes ]
values = [i for i in values if i != '']
```